# How to set parent callback to child state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At the very beginning, I would like to point out that I do not need to get a ready-made solution. I just need some guidance on how to do it properly.

I have parent component like this

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navigation.js";
import Start from "./components/Start.js";
import Generator from "./components/Generator.js";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.js";
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      window: 'start'
    };

    this.changeWindow = this.changeWindow.bind(this)
  }

  changeWindow() {
    this.setState({window: ''});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar update={this.changeWindow} />
        {this.state.window == 'start' ? (
        <Start />
        ) : (
        <Generator />
        )}
        <Footer />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

And child component like this

```
import React from "react";
import "./Navigation.css";

class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        option: 'start'
    }
}

optionChoose = event => {
    this.setState({
        option: event.target.value
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="class-select">
                    <select onChange={this.optionChoose}>
                        <option value="start">Wybierz klasę postaci</option>
                        <option value="bb">Barbarzyńca</option>
                        <option value="ryc">Rycerz</option>
                        <option value="sh">Sheed</option>
                        <option value="dr">Druid</option>
                        <option value="mo">Mag Ognia</option>
                        <option value="uk">Łucznik</option>
                        <option value="vd">VooDoo</option>
                    </select>
                    <span className="arrow"></span>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

My assumption is that the user selects an option in the child component and the value of the option is set to state. Later, the parent component calls back the child, gets its state, and sets it as its own.

Can someone tell me how to do it or show me on an example?

Comment: u could pass a function to the childcomponent which sets the state in the parent.

Comment: just need some clarification here. If you select an option from dropdown, that option is set as the window property value in the state of parent component?

Comment: @RajatJain I would like the child component to set its state using the value from the menu options. Then the parent component calls back to the child component, gets the child state and sets it as its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function changeWindow in App from Navbar. You have already added this function into Navbar as a prop named update.

In Navbar edit optionChoose to this

```
optionChoose = event => {
    update(event.target.value;
}
```

In App edit changeWindow to accept an argument

```
changeWindow(newValue) {
    this.setState({window: newValue});
  }
```

Also you're not using the state option in Navbar. It would be better to have one state in the parent component so you have a single source of data. Remove the state from Navbar and pass in the state as a prop to the Navbar component like this

```
    <Navbar option={this.state.window} update={this.changeWindow} />
```

Edit the select element to this

```
<select value={this.props.option} onChange={this.optionChoose}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems with what you are trying to do:

- In React, data flow is downwards, not the other way around. Parent component cannot access the state of the child component but the child component can receive some data from its parent component as props.
- Even if the parent component could access the state of its child component, you first update the state in the child component and then that state will be duplicated in the parent component. Don't duplicate the state when parent and child component can share the same state.

To solve your problem, keep the state in the parent component, pass a callback function to child component that will set the state in the parent component. When any option is selected in child component, call the callback function that was passed to child component as a prop.

When the parent component's state will be updated, it will trigger a re-render of the child component as well.

For further reading, see: [`React docs - Lifting State Up`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to maintain your **state** in the `parent component` and pass the **state** and update function via `props to the child component`.

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing down the `update` function, you just need to call it from the `Navbar`'s `optionChoose` handler:

```
optionChoose = event => {
    this.setState({
        option: event.target.value
    })
    this.props.update(); // maybe event.target.value as a parameter
}
```